# Continuous availability, 1st \2nd level caching of JPA inconsistency

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, jpa

We would like to have 2 tomcat servers that run the same web application.
We would have HA-Proxy as a load balancer \ proxy to manage connection \traffic\sessions.

Currently a new argument was brought to the table regarding the dangers in such architecture:

If you have 2 tomcats instances that run side by side, and use the same data source (mySQL for example) with JPA persistency manager,
You might have problems about cache syncing, since JPA uses a built in 1st level and 2nd level caches.

in other words, you will suffer sync issues since 2 JPA entity managers are active in different tomcats. (how does one know about invalidating its own cache when the second one do changes?)

Is this a real issue? Is there a way to configure something in order for it to work? 
if not , what are my options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding first level caching:**

First level cache is the persistence context bind with your entityManager. If you don't use extended PersistenceContext (or if you don't know what it is), then it's OK for you because your persistence context won't never live longer than one request-response loop. (and if it is the case you probably have more important design problem).

**Regarding 2nd level caching:**

2nd level caching means *sharing* data between multiple entityManager (it can be seen as a big *in memory map* where entityManager can "fetch" entity data, instead of running a query on the DB)

2nd level cache is optional in JPA2. If you are using hibernate and needs 2nd level cache you have to setup something like ehcache to support 2nd level cache. Otherwise you won't have 2nd level caching (BTW, I would be surprise if any JPA vendor provide a built-in 2nd level cache enabled by default).

So if you didn't enable 2nd level cache : no problems.
If you enable 2nd level cache you have to setup it correctly so that it broadcast messages to all your instances when some data change (With ehcahe : it means declaring broadcasts and listeners in ehcache xml config file).

---

I'm surprised ;-) , but it seems that some JPA vendors enable second level cache by default (DataNucleus)... and if you don't take care of it: you may have trouble in a distributed architecture.

Comment: FYI Some JPA impls do provide L2 cache on by default : DataNucleus JPA, and I think EclipseLink also. Obviously configuration of L2 cache to the precise situation being handled is advisable (e.g to use a distributed cache)